# VueJs component undefined

Tags: vue.js

I am new to [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js). The component, `comp1` doesn't appear to work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="example-2">
  <comp1></comp1>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var data1={selected: null, items:["degradant", "impurity"]};

Vue.component('comp1, {
  template:'<select v-model="selected">
             <option disabled value="">Please select</option>
             <option v-for="item in items" :value="item">{{item}}</option> 
           </select>',
  data: function(){
    return data1
  }            
});

new Vue({
  el: '#example-2'
})
```

Comment: Are you using single quotes `'` or backticks ` around the component template? Single quotes will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component should look like this:

```
Vue.component('comp1', {
  template:`<select v-model="selected">
             <option disabled value="">Please select</option>
             <option v-for="item in items" :value="item">{{item}}</option> 
           </select>`,
  data: function(){
    return data1
  }            
});
```

You were missing a single quote here: `'comp1, {`, and you have to surround multi-line templates with backticks, `.

```js
console.clear()

var data1={selected: null, items:["degradant", "impurity"]};

Vue.component('comp1', {
  template:`<select v-model="selected">
             <option disabled value="">Please select</option>
             <option v-for="item in items" :value="item">{{item}}</option> 
           </select>`,
  data: function(){
    return data1
  }            
});

new Vue({
  el: '#example-2'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="example-2">
  <comp1></comp1>
</div>
```