# how to use "v-for" for adding or removing a row with multiple components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i have a row with 3 components(in which is a defined component 1, component 2 and component 3, as showed in my previous question:
[VueJs component undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988212/vuejs-component-undefined) )

how can i add a row or remove a row (in which has 3 components) using v-for?

```
var data1={selected: null, items:["A", "B"]};

Vue.component('comp1', {
template: `<select v-model="selected">
         <option disabled value="">Please select</option>
         <option v-for="item in items" :value="item">{{item}}</option>
         </select>`,
data:function(){
      return data1
}              
});
 <!---similar for component 2 and 3---> 

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  rows:[]
  },
  methods:{
      addRow: function(){
          this.rows.push({});
              },
      removeRow: function(row){
           //console.log(row);
          this.rows.$remove(row);
             }
             },

        });
```

in .html

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
<div v-for ="row in rows">
  <comp1></comp1>
  <comp2></comp2>
  <comp3></comp3>
  <button @click="addRow">Add Row</button>
  <button @click="removeRow(row)">Remove Row</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is pretty close. Try this.

```js
console.clear()

const template = {
  template: `<select v-model="selected">
         <option disabled value="">Please select</option>
         <option v-for="item in items" :value="item">{{item}}</option>
         </select>`,
  data: function() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      items: ["A", "B"]
    }
  }
};

Vue.component("comp1", template)
Vue.component("comp2", template)
Vue.component("comp3", template)


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rows: []
  },
  computed:{
    newId(){
     return this.rows.length == 0 ? 1 : Math.max(...this.rows.map(r => r.id)) + 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow: function() {
      this.rows.push({id: this.newId });
    },
    removeRow: function(row) {
       this.rows.splice(this.rows.indexOf(row), 1)
    }
  },

});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
    <comp1></comp1>
    <comp2></comp2>
    <comp3></comp3>
    <button @click="removeRow(row)">Remove Row</button>
  </div>
  <button @click="addRow">Add Row</button>
</div>
```

This code moves the add row button outside the loop, because you don't really need multiple add row buttons. Additionally, [it adds a key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) for each `div` in the loop so that Vue can properly remove components when necessary. In order to generate the key, the code creates an `id` property for each new row object.